# How do I select a source room for the copy room function which has a larger room overlapping it entirely?

Tags: altium

How do I select the source for copy room function when the room I want to select has a larger room encompassing it entirely. Or to use the attached picture I'd like to use room 1 as a copy source for another target room not pictured. Room 2 is always selected for the copy function as a result of the nesting.

[image: Nested Rooms]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You get an opportunity to specify which room after clicking it in the source selection process:

1. Go do **Design** > **Rooms** > **Copy Room Formats**.
2. Click on the source room (1).
3. Select it from the "**Choose room**" dialog:

   [image: Choose Room]
4. Click on the target room (x).
5. Select it from the "**Choose room**" dialog, as well.

The room selection process does feel a little redundant in Altium Designer, in that you must specify the room(s) both by clicking and via the dialog. However it allows you to specify multiple target rooms by using a wildcard/multi-select.

Comment: For some reason the Choose Room dialog does not pop up and room (2) is selected. I have seen that dialog pop up previously but it doesn't always.

Comment: You might also try selecting the source room first, then selecting `Copy Room Formats` from the menu. Per the instructions at Altium (https://www.altium.com/documentation/altium-designer/pcb-room?version=21#!copying-room-formats) that's how they cover it. I'm not sure what causes the `Choose Room` dialog to (apparently selectively) appear.

Comment: No luck following those instructions. Even if room (1) is selected prior to selecting from the menu `Design->Rooms->Copy Room Formats` one click selects room (2) and a double click selects room (2) as the source and target.

Comment: Maybe it is a difference in Altium Designer version? I tested with 22.9.1. It may be worth checking if there's an option in preferences related to the "Choose Room" dialog. I was unable to get that dialog to _not_ appear.

Comment: Your suggestion did get me there but no dialog like the above. Under `PCB Editor->General->Display popup selection dialog`. This is the dialog that pops up for stacked objects in general but it will allow me to select the source room for the copy function. I'm running a previous version of Altium, 21.6.4, but I know I've seen that dialog before so... :shrug: But we did it so thank you!

Comment: Interesting; I have that option in preferences disabled. I'm glad it worked though! Perhaps someone else will find this post and add more insight later.

Comment: Figured it out. If `Room` in the selection filter properties is enabled it will not open the `Choose Room` dialog and will just select the top/largest room, in my case room (2). But if you disable `Room` from the selection filter the dialog will open.

Comment: If you want to add that as an answer I'll happily vote on it and mention it in mine. I am fairly sure I had that selection filter enabled but I can't check at the moment.